# ListMultimap asMap() -- modification while iterating?

Tags: java, multimap

So I have a `ListMultimap<Integer, List<someDataType>> containerSizeToDestQuanMap`. I am trying to iterate through it as follows:

```
Map<Integer, Collection<List<someDataType>>> sourceMapConverted = this.containerSizeToDestQuanMap.asMap();
for (Entry<Integer, Collection<List<DestQuanTuple>>> entry : sourceMapConverted.entrySet()) {
    // do something
```

If, when I "do something", I actually modify containerSizeToDestQuanMap, will I receive a `ConcurrentModificationException`? If so, is the only way to combat this to make a clone of my `containerSizeToDestQuanMap`, and iterate over that instead, modifying the original?

For instance, `//do something` could be:
`containerSizeToDestQuanMap.remove(something, something)`.

Comment: could you post more code?

Comment: Specifically, I want to remove k/v pairs in my `containerSizeToDestQuanMap`.

Comment: Yes, you can get into the same problems here that you do with normal collections.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing direct operations you have to use `Iterator`  on the `sourceMapConverted`.

Ex:

```
//iterating over keys only
for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + key);
}

//iterating over values only
for (Objvalue : map.values()) {
    System.out.println("Value = " + value);
}
```

While iterating you can do your modifications on iterator.